# Bolts for Fox Float RP2

Tags: parts, suspension

I saw my bolt was loose on my mountain bike, so I turned back home, but ended up losing it along the road. I had to walk the bike home because my rear shock (Fox Float RP2) to my bike (Gary Fisher HiFi Deluxe 29er). The shock is connected by two bolts to the bike. I am missing the bottom one. Does anyone know where I can look up this part for purchase or if it is a common part that I don't need a specific one? I've learned lots about this bike just from breaking it so many times, but I can see I have plenty to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shock bolt size and threading can vary a fair bit. At least they also tend to be easy to find. I believe that takes an `M6 x 1.0mm` bolt. Probably about a centimeter long. If a `5mm` allen wrench is the right size, I'm probably right. It could also be an `M8 x 1.25mm`, or even `M8 x 1.00mm`. All of these can be found in any bicycle shop and most hardware stores. I'd recommend dealing with it in person though because online shopping / shipping is slow and you'll get very frustrated if you get it wrong.